# Jquery expand and scroll at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if the following is possible. Currently I have some code which opens a DIV at the bottom of the page using jquery. It is something as simple as this:

```
$("#country_slide").slideToggle();
```

Then I have some example code which scrolls to the bottom of the page (just an example):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
```

The trouble is this div that opens up will be off the bottom of the page when it expands, so I want it to not only open but also have the page scroll down to show the now opened div as it is opening.

I can only work out how to fully expand the div, then scroll to the availible area. I want both processes to run at the same time, not one after the other.

Is this possible with jquery, and if it is, can someone please explain how.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce them not happening at the same time. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBT7m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjrafferty/qELbe/5/)

I am calling the events, to display (show, fadeIn, slideDown, etc..) and scroll to element, when the $(document) is ready.

I placed timers in milliseconds for the display function at 3 seconds, and the scroll to at 4 seconds. You can adjust these times as necessary to display your hidden element as you see fit.

CSS

```
 #container{height:850px;background-color:red;width:300px;text-align:center; }
 #bottomDiv{display:none;position:relative;top:400px;width:260px;height:200px; background-color:dodgerblue;margin:20px auto;border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center;}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="container" style="height:1500px;background-color:red;width:300px;">
      <p>I'm opening a div and scrolling below</p>
      <div id="bottomDiv" class="tempCss">Bottom Div</div>
 </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#bottomDiv").slideDown(3000);
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#bottomDiv").offset().top }, 4000,function(){
       });  
   });
```